# Jquery ajax post to disable enable fields and get response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have an ajax call that i disable a fields and i then want to enable again once the ajax has finished. How i can re-enable a fields ?

My jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form-signin').submit(function(){

    $( "#response" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    $('#response').html("<div class='message loading-response'>Loading...</div>");

    var $inputs = $(this).find("input, select, button, textarea"); //line 6
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true); //line 7

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'form.php', 
        data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $('#response').html(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Submit failed." );
        $('#response').html("<div class='message loading-response'>Submit failed.</div>");

    });
    request.always(function () { //line 23
            // reenable the inputs line 24
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false); //line 25
        }); //line 26
    return false;

});});
```

result of the code above:

1. clicked submit
2. fields disable
3. display response (loading...)
4. hidden response
5. fields not enable again

if i remove line 6-7 and 23-26:

1. clicked submit
2. fields disable
3. display response (loading...)
4. hidden response
5. **display response from PHP action**
6. fields not enable again

My PHP action

```
<script>$('#response').html('<div class=\'message error\'>Error login username <?php echo $_POST['username-signin']; ?></div>');</script>
```

How i get:

1. clicked submit
2. fields disable
3. display response (loading...)
4. hidden response
5. **display response from PHP action**
6. **fields enable again**

edit:
my demo work http://jsfiddle.net/TkyyC/
but it still doesnt work in my localhost.

edit2:
just disable a button

```
$('.sidebarsignin #submit-signin').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

.sidebarsignin is class my div inside form and
submit-signin is id button
thanks for all

Comment: What jquery version are you using?

Comment: i'm use jquery 1.10.2

Comment: If you disable all of your inputs they're not going to be serialized and sent as part of your AJAX request. Assuming you're ok with that, what happens if you just return the content for the `#response` element rather than a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.removeAttr("")`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/). You can remove the `disabled` attribute to set the input enabled. I created a [JSFiddle-Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YE46r/).

Comment: But it should, as you can see in my example :) . If it's not working, your script is probably not correct. Try to create a not working example on JSFiddle so we can fix it and show you the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

On send:
$("#yourfield").attr("disabled", "disabled");

On success:
$("#yourfield").removeAttr("disabled");

Verify if your ajax call succeeded so the program will execute proper code.

Answer (score 0):

```
.done(function(data){
        $('#response').html(data);
        $("#inputID").removeAttr("disabled");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'form.php', 
data: $(this).serialize(),
beforeSend: function(){
$inputs.prop("disabled", true);
},
})
.done(function(data){
$('#response').html(data);
$("input, select, button, textarea").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Please add a few words of explanation.